# Arc length parametrisation is reparametrisation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was trying to show that if $\gamma : [a,b] \to \mathbb R^3$ is a curve and $$ p(t) = \int_{t_0}^t |\gamma'(\tau)|d\tau$$ where $t_0 \in [a,b]$ then $p^{-1}: [c,d] \to [a,b]$ is a reparametrisation of $\gamma$. This is exercise 2 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/199450).

But I am not even sure what I need to show:

1. $p^{-1}$ is a bijection
2. and $(p^{-1})'(s) \neq 0$ for all $s$
3. and $\gamma ( p^{-1}(s)) = \gamma (s)$ for all $s$?

I tried to show 3. but the problem is that it does not even have same domain on both side. How to show that $p^{-1}$ is a reparametrisation of $\gamma$? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must show that $p^{-1}$ is continuous and injective. To achieve this it is enough to show that $p$ is strictly increasing and continuous.

**some details**

You have a $C^1$ function $\gamma\colon [a,b]\to \mathbb R^3$ with $|\gamma'(t)|\neq 0$ for all $t$ and define
$$
  p(t) = \int_a^t |\gamma'(\tau)|\, d\tau.
$$
Let $L=p(b)$. L is the length of the curve $\gamma$. The function
$$
  p\colon [a,b] \to [0,L]
$$
is differentiable and increasing because by the fundamental theorem of calculus:
$$
  p'(t) = |\gamma'(t)| > 0.
$$
Hence $p$ is a bijection. It is injective because it is strictly increasing. It is surjective in view of the intermediate values theorem since $p(0)=0$, $p(b)=L$. So $p$ is invertible. Since $p'(t)\neq 0$ the inverse is also differentiable and 
$$
  (p^{-1})'(s) = \frac{1}{p'(p^{-1}(s))}> 0.
$$

Comment: These points are in [definition of reparametrisation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Reparametrization_and_equivalence_relation). Are they nonsense?

Comment: 2. is nonsense because 0 has no relevant role for the function $p$.

Comment: 3. is nonsense as you have already noticed in your post

Comment: In $2$ I meant to write "$(p^{-1})' \neq 0$". Is it nonsense still?

Comment: The derivative different from 0 makes sense. But only if you are interested in differentiable reparameterizations, in general I would not require it.

Comment: How did you find out that $p^{-1}$ must be continuous and injective? What does it not have to be surjective also? (It seems to me that if I want to go from one map to the other an vice versa then the parametrisation $p$ has to be bijective?) I am sorry but I am new to this.

Comment: I added some details.

Comment: Many thank you. I understand now. We show it is injective because that shows that it is invertible.

Comment: I now understand it better! Thank you! The 3 should be: $p^{-1}(s) = \gamma (s)$ (using information on reparametrization on Wikipedia).

Comment: @user58975: 3 should be $\gamma(p^{-1}(p(t))) = \gamma(t)$ which is somewhat trivial.

Comment: I posted a summary of my understanding XD

Comment: Maybe we can say $p$ is surjective by definition since $[0,L]=p([a,b])$? Or would it be wrong and we have to use intermediate value theorem?

Comment: By definition $L=p(b)$ and $0=p(a)$, so the extremes are reached. To prove the intermediate values are reached you must use the corresponding theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Using definition and notations from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Reparametrization_and_equivalence_relation):

Let
$\gamma_1 = \gamma$, $i: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3 , x \mapsto (x,0,0)$, 
$\gamma_2 = i \circ p^{-1}$ and
$\phi = \mathrm{id}$.

Then $\phi' \neq 0$ and $\gamma_2(\phi(x))= \gamma_1 (x)$ are immediate. To finish proof all that remains to be shown is that $\gamma$ and $p^{-1}$ have the same properties. Here it means one must verify that $p^{-1}$ is well-defined and continuous (= is a continuous function because $\gamma$ is assumed to be a curve).  (Or maybe also differentiable, as assumed in Emanuele's answer)

To show that it is well-defined, one must show $p$ is invertible. A map $p$ is invertible if it is bijective.

To show that it is continuous use that differentiable => continuous (Emanuele's answer)

Comment: $\gamma_2(s) = \gamma(p^{-1}(s))$, in your definition $\gamma_2$ is not a curve (it has values in $\mathbb R$ not $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini I corrected it! :-)