# Any reparametrization of a regular curve is regular

Tags: geometry

In A.Pressley's book, 
there is a proposition "Any reparametrization of   a regular curve is regular".

In its proof, the author used the Chain Rule to the equation (Φ ο Ψ)(t) = t, where Φ is the reparametriztion map and Ψ its inverse,
and he concluded the differential of Φ is not zero.

But, I doubt the proof because to apply the Chain Rule, the two functions should be check whether they are differentiable or not.
For example, if we take the reparametriztion curve β(t)=(cost^3, sont^3) of γ(t)=(cost, sint), t ∈ (-1, 1), the β is singular at t=0. But γ is obiously regular.

I ask you that is Pressley's proof correct?????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A re-parametrization is by definition a smooth map with nowhere vanishing derivative. A regular curve is by definition a smooth curve with nowhere vanishing derivative. Therefore, a re-parametrization of a regular curve is regular by the chain rule.

In particular, your example isn't a counterexample because the derivative of $\beta$ vanishes at $0$ (as you note) and so $\beta$ isn't a re-parametrization (by definition). (Moreover, the range of $\beta$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$; the domain and codomain of a re-parametrization are required to be open intervals so this is another reason $\beta$ isn't a re-parametrization.)

I also recommend you to see my answer here for more details:

[How (and why) would I reparameterize a curve in terms of arclength?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199417/how-and-why-would-i-reparameterize-a-curve-in-terms-of-arclength/199450#199450)

I hope this helps!

Comment: haha..... I realize my big mistake......TT
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @JeongNam-ho If you're satisfied with any answer on this website, then you can upvote by clicking the arrow pointing upward to the left of the answer. If the answer is to a question that you have posed (such as this one), then you can accept it by clicking the tick mark just below the pair of arrows to the left of the answer.

Comment: oh....... I`m so sorry.... But this question is my first trial in this website... Thanks a lot!!