# arclength parametrization intuition

Tags: calculus, soft-question, parametric

I have a question about parametric curves. I have learnt about arc length re parametrization and I understand how do the problems , for example finding the length of the vector and integrating with respect to another variable and solving for it. However I feel like I don't fully understand the geometric intuition of this , like what it really is doing and what It means ? Could anyone help shed some light on this ?

Why is it that it is common to define curvature with respect to arc length for example?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The speed of drawing the curve in the standard parametrization is $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be helpful to you: [How (and why) would I reparameterize a curve in terms of arclength?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199417/how-and-why-would-i-reparameterize-a-curve-in-terms-of-arclength)

And here's a derivation of the fact that the velocity under arclength parametrization is a unit vector. This property shows the behavior of this parametrization to admit intrinsic properties of curves. From here we may build formulas for curvature and torsion - two characteristics that uniquely determine each curve.

\begin{align}
&s = \int_{0}^{t} \mid\alpha^{'}(t) \mid \\\\
&\frac{ds}{dt} = \mid\alpha^{'}(t) \mid \\\\
&\frac{dt}{ds} = \frac{1}{\mid\alpha^{'}(t) \mid}\\\\
&\alpha^{'}(s) = \frac{d\alpha}{ds} = \frac{d\alpha}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds}= \alpha^{'}(t)\frac{1}{\mid\alpha^{'}(t) \mid}\\\\
&\mid \alpha^{'}(s) \mid = \mid \alpha^{'}(t){\frac{1}{\mid \alpha^{'}(t)\mid }\mid} = 1.
\end{align}